# Can I dynamically set new object name

Tags: php, oop

I want to create objects dynamically. Right now I'm creating them manually like this

```
$obj1 = new Prefix_Myobj();
$obj2 = new Prefix_Other();
$obj3 = new Prefix_Another();
```

How can I set the part after `Prefix_` dynamically? I tried this but it didn't work

```
$name = 'Myobj';
$obj1 = new Prefix_{$name}();
```

Comment: I'm too rusty to provide a full answer. Something with variable-variables though and the `$$` operator

Comment: I deleted my answer. Good catch, Peter. This is dynamic type specification, not dynamic object naming. I was reading this terribly wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a string that specifies the entire class name.

```
$name = 'Myobj';
$classname = 'Prefix_'.$name;
$obj1 = new $classname();
```

However, it might be better design to build a class registry of sorts rather than generating class names on the fly like this.

Comment: If the class is in a specific namespace, you need to inform the full path

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? Maybe there is a better solution for your problem; multiton or dependency injection etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is important to say that if your class is in a specific namespace, you need to inform the full path. Example:

```
namespace my\path\app;

class MyClass {

    $name = 'Myobj';
    $classname = 'my\path\app\Prefix_' . $name;
    $obj1 = new $classname();
}
```